# SSRS 2014 invalid namespace

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, reporting

I am trying to set up forms authentication on Reporting Server 2014. So far I was able to get rid of most of the errors but when trying to log in on `reportserver/logon.aspx` I get the following error:

> An error occurred while attempting to get the ReportServer Url. Invalid namespace

I applied the following in web.config:

```
<add key="ReportServer" value="localhost"/> 
<add key="ReportServerInstance" value="RS_SKOREPORTS"/>
```

The following is from my `reportingservices.mof`:

```
#pragma namespace ("\\\\.\\root\\Microsoft\\SqlServer\\ReportServer\\RS_SKOREPORTS\\V12")
```

I've tried several things like removing the `RS_` prefix but the error remains.

EDIT:
Ok, I have come to the point where I know what's wrong by debugging everything, I just don't know how to fix it. My `wmiNamespace` string is adjusted for report server 2014 as follows: `private const string wmiNamespace = @"\\{0}\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_{1}\v12";`

The weird thing is that when I debug the login process and put a watch on `fullWmiNamespace` the value it returns is:

```
"\\\\localhost\\root\\Microsoft\\SqlServer\\ReportServer\\RS_SKOREPORTS\\v10"
```

It looks like report server ignores the changes I made in `AuthenticationUtilities.cs` and just uses the unmodified version.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by hardcoding the wmiNamespace string. For some reason the FullWmiNamespace string didn't format the string properly..